# Why is this simple jQuery snippet not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, append

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo() {
    $(this).parent('li').append('hello world');
}
</script>

<ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a3981906ca415e0ec3e051076b71b0cd?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" onClick="foo()" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8ec1383b240b5ba15ffb9743fceb3c0e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" onClick="foo()" /></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to append the string "hello world" to the `<li>` that contains the image that was just clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need to attach onclick. With jQuery just do

```
$('li').click(function(){
$(this).append('hello world')
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/tFr5y/

Comment: does it not add this functionality to each and every li in that page?

Comment: To restrict it to specific set of li's you need to specify the UL id.  ex: `$('li','#ulid').click(..)`.

Comment: +1 : for jQuey specific solution for event handling. It is waste of power adding jQuery but not using it for registering event handlers :)

Answer (score 2):

Because in `foo` function `this` is undefined, function does not know which element is triggering event.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    function foo(elem)
    {
        $(elem).parent('li').append('asdf');

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <li><img  src="source" onclick="foo(this)" /></li>

    <li><img  src="source" onclick="foo(this)" /></li>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two changes

[1] Add a parameter in foo

```
function foo(me) {
    $(me).parent('li').append('hello world');  
}
```

[2] pass parameter in foo in onClick

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a3981906ca415e0ec3e051076b71b0cd?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" onClick="foo(this)" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/8ec1383b240b5ba15ffb9743fceb3c0e?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" onClick="foo(this)" /></li>
</ul>
```